# How do I get the current URL in Python or attach BeautifulSoup to the current URL

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to use BeautifulSoup to parse a HTML page and extract some of the content. The problem I have is that the URL I need to parse is dynamic so I can't hard code it into urllib2.urlopen like all the examples of BeautifulSoup show.

I was trying to extract the current URL from the browser using SELF but I couldn't get this to work. Can anyone post an example of how I can extract the current URL from the browser using SELF, or how I can attach BeautifulSoup to the current URL?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my code so far:

```
import os
import time

import win32api
import win32com.client
import win32con

from pywinauto import application

class A(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.x = self.request.url

  def method_a(self):
    print self.x

#start IE with a start URL of what was passed in
app = application.Application()
app.Start(r"c:\program files\internet explorer\iexplore.exe %s"% "http://www.cyclestreets.net/journey")
time.sleep(3)
#ie = app.window_(title_re = "CycleStreets Cycle journey planner")
ie = app.window_(title_re = ".*CycleStreets.*")

a = A()
a.method_a()
```

When I run this I get a message saying AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'request'

Comment: Where's your URL coming from? Show us your current code and someone might be able to help you out... Is the dynamic URL part of the `BeautifulSoup` parsed HTML page?

Comment: Struggling to post the code into the comment (the backticks don't format it very well) so I'll add it into an answer below.

Comment: Right, OK - new to StackOverflow too :)

Comment: What exactly is `class A` supposed to be? It does _not_ have an attribute `request` which explains your `AttributeError`. Please clarify what you intend to do.

Comment: I'm trying to get the current URL from the browser. There's a highly rated answer on another SO thread [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764586/get-current-url-in-python) stating that I can use self.request.url but I'm clearly missing something.

Comment: The other SO thread is using Google's `appengine` which has a `self.request.url` attribute; in your code, it is not available, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think you've gotten a little confused. In your class 'A' you have this:

```
class A(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.x = self.request.url
```

In which you are setting the value of x, in your init function to self.request.url. This is then complaining, as self.request does not exist at this time in your object.

Comment: I'm still no closer to understanding how I can get the current URL in a Python script - can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You can get current url with urllib
see the example below:

```
from urllib import request,response
url = "http://www.example.com"
response=request.Request(url,headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36'})
print(response.get_full_url())
```

This may help you!....