# Get URL sub subdomain

Tags: python, url

I'm using the following Python snippet to get a URL:

```
address = self.request.url
```

This gives me the URL when it looks like:

```
http://domain.tld
```

or

```
http://sub.domain.tld
```

But my URL looks like this:

```
http://sub.sub.domain.tld
```

In this case the code doesn't return a URL at all. In the end I have to get the first 'sub' domain from the URL. But I can't continue if the code doesn't work when a URL has two subdomains.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: What library is generating this particular request object?

Comment: What code does `self.request.url` come from? Python's urllib2? Or a Python web framework?

Comment: @H.Dunlop I have this at the top: **from urlparse import urlparse**. http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html --- Really no idea if its standard  stuff. Never really touched python before...

Comment: @w00: please include more code.

Comment: You might have to give still more context. urlparse doesn't have anything to do with request objects. Where is this code from?

Comment: @H.Dunlop You're right, i removed the import and it still works. I got it from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764586/get-current-url-in-python --- I guess it belongs in the Goole App Engine API (i'm using that). But really, any code that gives me the entire URL including all subdomains will do. I'd like to show more code, but i really have no idea what else to show.

Comment: Ah okay, so it's the GAE request object which inherits from WebOb - http://docs.webob.org/en/latest/reference.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK with plain python script,

```
import urlparse
address = urlparse("http://sub.sub.domain.tld")

print address.netloc
print address.path
print address.scheme
```

Comment: Plain python is fine. But how do i get the URL? It can't be hardcoded. And that's mainly the problem i'm facing right now :)

Answer (score 0):

From the information provided I can't give you an answer per se. But I can give some troubleshooting information. If the request.url is empty then there is probably another reason that it is not being populated.

I understand that this is a GAE request object. Which inherits from WebOb.

The request object has a number of other attributes. Try printing them all and seeing what they contain.

```
print self.request.host
print self.request.host_url
print self.request.scheme   # should be 'http'
```

If these are all empty then it sounds like the request object is not being created properly.  That could be your underlying problem.

Comment: Thanks, i tried them all. And they work fine untill i use an URL which has 2 subdomains. Then it's all empty. I'll try the App Engine discussion groups too. Perhaps it's just a bug. I'll also leave this question open for a few hours. You never know what other answer i might get. Otherwise i'll mark your answer as accepted. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: No worries, that is a bit weird. So what does self.request.host assigned to it? Just the base domain name?

Comment: self.request.host gives me the entire URL without http(s):// infront of it. It's just empty when my url contains 2 subdomains.

Comment: So self.request.host joined with the self.request.scheme would basically give you what you want then?

Comment: Yes, if they worked. But they don't when my url consists out of 2 subdomains.

Comment: Okay, so the self.request object is not getting created properly. It sounds like a bug in whatever code you are using to create the request object. If you show us that code then we might be able to see the problem. There is no inherent bug in WebOb that prevents you using sub, subdomains.

Answer (score 0):

What self.request.url is from seems unanswered. It reminds me of google app engine though, so in the off-chance that you are using GAE, you can use

```
self.request.host_url
```

to get the host url or

```
self.request.path_url
```

to get the url without the query parameters.

Source: http://docs.webob.org/en/latest/reference.html

My apologies if this has nothing to do with what you're asking.