# How to get current url in Google App Engine python with jinja templating

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

I'm using Google App Engine for Python with Jinja2 templating. Is there a template tag to get the URL of the current page. Or do I have to pass the url as a variable to the template from the view code?

Comment: According to @mgilson, this can't be done. :( A [global](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#jinja2.Template.globals) function seems like the best alternative.

Answer (score 12):

`{{ request.url }}` gives the current url.  Do you need the full url, or just the path relative to the root?

For example, using Flask, you can have

```
{{ request.url }}
{{ request.base_url }}
{{ request.url_root }}
{{ request.host_url }}
{{ request.path }}
```

etc.

Comment: But you'd have to pass `request` to `template.render` -- I think OP wants it to just be there which (I think) is non-trivial at best ... -- Possibly a [`global`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#jinja2.Template.globals) function which uses `webapp2.get_request().url`?

Comment: What good is a template if you don't render it?  This should be in the `context` params passed when rendering.

Comment: Not saying that I disagree -- And this it should be easy enough to always pass it via a particular function in a base `webapp2.RequestHandler` -- I was merely pointing out that it this answer doesn't quite fit the bill.

Comment: Self has all that information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764586/get-current-url-in-python