# get active url on chrome and firefox using python

Tags: python-3.x

I work with python 3.7 on windows and I want to write a script that print the actual active urls on browsers (chrome and firefox), I found the script:
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open(the url)
but this script allows to open the url not to find the active urls.
can someone help me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764586/get-current-url-in-python/2764822 Does this answer your query ?

Answer (score 1):

Here you need to download and install `pywin32` and import these modules in your script like this -

```
import win32gui
import win32con

#to get currently active windows
window = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow
```

Or to get the Google Chrome window handle

> [win32gui.FindWindow](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.5/pywin32/win32gui__FindWindow_meth.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use selenium module and loop through all open tabs.

This code prints all open tabs of chrome and firefox:

```
from selenium import webdriver

chromeDriver = webdriver.Chrome()
firefoxDriver = webdriver.Firefox()


for handle in chromeDriver.window_handles[0]:
    chromeDriver.switch_to.window(handle)
    print(chromeDriver.current_url)

for handle in firefoxDriver.window_handles[0]:
    firefoxDriver.switch_to.window(handle)
    print(firefoxDriver.current_url)
```

**Note:**

This code is inefficient and should change to use only one loop.